# Es posible pasar el valor de X al input text?

Tags: javascript

Debo enumerar una columna, Sistema#1, Sistema#2 consecutivamente... Tengo algo que controla la cantidad máxima de filas a agregar y me gustaría reutilizarlos para agregar ese valor de X al input, es posible?

El valor de `X` en el donde se encuentra `console.log(x)`

```
$(addButton).click(function () {
        if (x < maxField) {
            x++;
            console.log(x)
            $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML);
        }
});
```

El html completo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- CSRF Token -->
<meta name="csrf-token" content="kDjxb8qGwr5zdBQ5cDNB1gC4yKRu18ZzVTz6AJNO">

<title></title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
    <div class="content mt-5">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">

                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="table-responsive-sm">
                        <table class="table">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Sistema</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody class="item">
                                <tr>
                                    <td><input class="form-control system" name="type[]" type="text" value="Sistema #"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                         <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 pb-4 text-center">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-primary add_button col-md-2 col-xs-12"> Agregar Ítem</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var maxField = 16;
    var addButton = $('.add_button');
    var wrapper = $('.item');
    var fieldHTML = 
            '<tr>' +
                '<td>' +
                '<input type="text" id="type[]" name="type[]" class="form-control system" value="Sistema #'+ console.log(x) +'">' +
                '</td>' +
            '<tr>'; 

        var x = 1;
        $(addButton).click(function () {
            if (x < maxField) {
                x++;
                console.log(x)
                $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segun el codigo que tienes podrias hacer esto

```
var x = 0;
                        $(addButton).click(function () {

                            if (x < maxField) {
                                x++;
                                var fieldHTML =
                                        '<tr>' +
                                        '<td>' +
                                        '<input type="text" id="type[]" name="type[]" class="form-control system" value="Sistema #' + x + '">' +
                                        '</td>' +
                                        '<tr>';
                                $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML);
                            }
                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

En la plantilla `fieldHTML` quitar la propiedad `value`. Luego en la función crear un objeto Jquery usando la plantilla, buscar su elemento interior de tipo input y asignarle el value.

```
var fieldHTML = 
            '<tr>' +
                '<td>' +
                '<input type="text" id="type[]" name="type[]" class="form-control system">' +
                '</td>' +
            '<tr>'; 

        var x = 1;
        $(addButton).click(function () {
            if (x < maxField) {
                x++;
                console.log(x)
                // crear elemento html desde la plantilla
                $field = $(fieldHTML);
                // buscar el input y establecer su value
                $field.find('input').val(`Sistema #${x}`);
                // agregar el nuevo elemento
                $(wrapper).append($field);
            }
        });
    });
```

Una mejor forma es separar el html del código js, para eso se puede usar la etiqueta `template`, esa sirve para colocar código html que no es renderizado:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var maxField = 16;
    var addButton = $('.add_button');
    var wrapper = $('.item');
    
        var x = 1;
        $(addButton).click(function () {
            if (x < maxField) {
                x++;
                console.log(x)
                // crear elemento html desde el cuerpo del template
                $template = $($("#template").html());
                // buscar elemento input y asignarle su valor
                $template.find("input").val(`Sistema # ${x}`);
                $(wrapper).append($template);
            }
        });
    });
</script>


<template id="template">
<tr>
  <td>
   <input type="text" id="type[]" name="type[]" class="form-control system">
  </td>
</tr>
</template>
```

Comment: Gracias, ya lo pruebo, aunque creo que debo hacer un cambio, para simplificar coloqué un solo input en el ejemplo, tengo varios.